# Mouse Click Through Scripting on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, macros, click, applescript

Trying to map a remote so I can use it to manipulate my music software, and to do this I want to be able to move the mouse around and click it. All the solutions I've found (e.g. MouseTools, AppleScript built-in click functions, Apple's Accessibility "MouseKeys" click-to-key function) seem to be overly fussed about layers, windows etc, trying to funnel the click to the application and ask what it wants to do about it. One AppleScript error proclaimed "Failed to click."

My question is, what's a Terminal command/AppleScript function I can use to do a simple, normal click as though I had done it from the trackpad - as in, it bloody clicks, without caring what's beneath, but just does it and processes the consequences (opens window, selects window, anything, I don't care but I just want it to normally click as though it were actually a physical trackpad click).

I'm tearing my hair out over this because it seems that Apple has tried to prevent any software solution from doing anything that might come close to an actual global click. Any solutions? Thanks :)

Comment: You should ask this question at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting with MouseTools? I've never used it, but I've seen it before, and it looks like it's supposed to do exactly what you are looking for: move the cursor to a location and click that location. The docs don't show anything about layers or windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading [AppleScript toolbox scripting addition.](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/)  Once installed in the proper locations, in Script Editor.app, , you will be able to use commands from the key and mouse suite from the AppleScript toolbox dictionary to…get, set, and click at mouse locations (coordinates)

Here is some sample code using commands from the AppleScript toolbox dictionary

---

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
set mousePointLocation1 to {745, 110} -- The Collapsed Menu
set mousePointLocation2 to {780, 340} -- TV Link In The Menu
set mousePointLocation3 to {885, 180} -- Apple TV 4K Icon

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes
activate application "Safari"
delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation1 ¬
    number of clicks 1

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation2 ¬
    number of clicks 1

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation3 ¬
    number of clicks 1
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
-- For Demonstration Purposes
-- Gives Me Time To Put The Mouse Where I Want
delay 3

-- Gets Coordinates Of The Current Mouse Location
set currentMouseLocation to AST mouse point location

-- Mouse Click At Defined Location
AST click at currentMouseLocation ¬
    number of clicks 2 -- How Many Clicks
```

[image]

---

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
set mousePointLocation to {20.0, 20.0}

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST set mouse point location mousePointLocation ¬
    without holding mouse down

delay 1 -- For Demonstration Purposes

AST click at mousePointLocation ¬
    number of clicks 1
```

[image]

Comment: What's the proper location to install it, I can't create ScriptingAdditions folder in Script Editor.app and moving it to `/Library/ScriptingAdditions` or `~/Library/ScriptingAdditions` doesn't make any difference still getting the error that AST commands unrecognized?