# Jump to specific cell in google spreadsheets macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am aware of f5 to open the jump to cell dialog, the problem with it, is that, while it allows you to do it once, the next time you press f5, to jump to another specific cell, the previous text is not highlighted, therefore you need to get you hands off the keyboard and select it with the mouse.

If I could have a way where I don't lift my hands from the keyboard it would speed up my workflow tremendously.

Any ideas?

Like, I'd need a macro to pop up the goto range dialog AND select whatever text is there so that I can just type a new cell range (e.g: a391)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around for MacOS (High Sierra, probably it will work on newer os as well)

I downloaded the file `AppleScript Toolbox.osax` from here: https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/

Put the file in the folder: `/Users/me/Library/ScriptingAdditions`

Run `Automator` and start a new Service:

[image]

[image]

Paste this script

```
activate application "Firefox" -- or "Safari" or "Chrome", etc
set mousePointLocation1 to {1700, 250} -- coordinates depend on your screen size
AST click at mousePointLocation1 number of clicks 1
```

And save:

[image]

Go to `Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Services` and add shortcut for this service

[image]

After that you will see the new shortcut here:

[image]

In Google Spreadsheet I press `F5`, to show the panel and then I press `^F5` and cursor jump on this panel and does click.

I'm a noob in macOS I'm sure it can be done better. It's just how I managed to do it right now.

Another modification of the script could be more convenient:

```
activate application "Firefox"

tell application "System Events" 
  key code 96 -- this is F5 key
end tell

delay .5

AST click at {1700, 250} number of clicks 2 -- or 3 maybe
```

This way you don't need to press `F5`. Just press `^F5` and go ahead.

---

It works

[image]

---

Just in case. If you know Python. I've managed to press `F5` move and click mouse with Python module `pynput`:

```
from pynput import mouse, keyboard

k = keyboard.Controller()
k.press(keyboard.Key.f5)
k.release(keyboard.Key.f5)

m = mouse.Controller()
m.position = (1700, 240)
m.press(mouse.Button.left)
m.release(mouse.Button.left)
m.click(mouse.Button.left, 2)
```

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It can be converted into macOS Service this way:

[image]

And then you can run this Service the same way via `Keyboard` > `Services` > `Add Shortcut`

Comment: Thank you, i followed all of your steps but unfortunately 
I get an error when I try to run it. It says:

Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier 

My script reads:
activate application "Chrome" 
set mousePointLocation1 to {903, 270}
AST click at mousePointLocation1 number of clicks 1

if I can make it work it is exactly what I need.

Comment: Try to comment out the first line like this: `-- activate application "Chrome"` And what version of macOS you're using? I just copied the text from your comment and it works fine. See my update.

Comment: I am using Mojave (10.14) still same error. It highlights the word click when I get it, I don't know if that means anything at all. 

I tried with and without the line activate application "Chrome" or activate application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 
Same error :(

Comment: I think it deserves a new question. "How can I perform mouse double click at given coordinates with keyboard shortcut on Mojave?". Frankly, my knowledge of MacOS is quite miserable.

Comment: I've added the Python solution. Just in case

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple approach to add customized macros to Sheets. You only need to create a [bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) beforehand that contains a `function` with your desired actions. Then you can follow these steps:

1. Go to `Tools > Macros > Import`
2. Find your function and click on `Add Function` and click on the `X` to close.
3. Go to `Tools > Macros > Manage Macros`
4. Assign a number to your macro and click on `Update`
5. Run your macro using `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + {NUMBER}`

Following those steps you will create a customized macro without difficulty, but feel free to ask me any doubts.

Comment: the import function is disabled on google sheets now, unfortunately. 
I have a friend of mine doing a simple dialog macro for excel which I tried to import but it didn't work.

Comment: To enable this menu you need to create some script(s) before. `Tools` ▸ `Script Editor` etc. But I'm afraid you can't jump between cells via script. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts in Google Spreadsheets are rather suck. If you're on Windows I'd advice to try [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). It can move cursor at any coordinates on your screen (coordinates can be set relative current window). For example 'Win+F5' could work as F5 + move cursor at top-right corner of the screen and perform a left click.

Comment: unfortunately i am using a macbook

Comment: Probably you can do something alike on MacOS this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561117/14265469

Answer (score 0):

I just found another a much more obvious native solution.

Put the code in Script Editor:

```
function jump() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Input cell').getResponseText();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).activate();
}
```

Save it and add the function as a macros:

[image]

[image]

Then assign some shortcut to the macros:

[image]

[image]

After that you can press the shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> in my case), input cell address, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and here we go.

[image]